# Identifying the structure of an amino acid from NMR spectra

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, amino-acids

I have the <sup>1</sup>H, <sup>13</sup>C, and DEPT spectra of an unknown compound, listed in text form below, but I have also attached original images of the spectra. I know that it is an amino acid that has a cyclic structure and a relative molecular mass of 145. I'm supposed to deduce the structure, but am having some trouble with it:

<sup>1</sup>H NMR (in D<sub>2</sub>O): 4.2 ppm (1H, s), 3.85 ppm (1H, dd), 3.2 ppm (2H, m), 2.1 ppm (1H, d), 1.8 ppm (3H, m) ([image of spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2KaR.jpg))

<sup>13</sup>C NMR: 174.27 ppm (quaternary), 61.92 ppm (CH<sub>2</sub>), 54.09 ppm (CH<sub>2</sub>), 38.69 ppm (CH/CH<sub>3</sub>), 32.87 ppm (CH/CH<sub>3</sub>), 28.04 ppm (CH/CH<sub>3</sub>) ([image of 1D <sup>13</sup>C spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmmaF.jpg); [image of DEPT spectrum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ9Tx.jpg))

From the spectral data, I can tell that the compound doesn't have an aromatic ring, but beyond that I don't know how to proceed. Unfortunately, although it would be really helpful, I'm not able to determine the coupling constants in the <sup>1</sup>H spectrum.